# Lightbox2 Not Working in Chrome, Messes Up Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, lightbox2

For a couple of days I'd been trying to get Lokesh Dhakar's Lightbox2 to work on my art portfolio website.
After much coding, re-coding and re-coding, I finally got it to work (especially thanks to Ayan, who was most helpful).

However, a new problem is that it shows up fine in **IE**, but **not in Chrome**. It fails in mobile Chrome on my phone as well.
When I click on the thumbnail in Chrome, it makes my page scroll all the way to a far-down bottom and opens the image there with no navigation buttons or anything.
How do I fix this??

I have provided my page's code below. (Please note that I am aware that only the 'portfolio' page and 'index' are working; this site is still brand new.)

I am using CDNs for the Lightbox2 CSS and javascript, because for some reason using local versions of these files did not work at all.

LIVE SITE: http://art.juniebug.net/portfolio.html

Any help would be much, MUCH appreciated! Thank you!!

CODE BELOW:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html><head>
<meta name="Author" content="Janna Correa">


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<style>
<!--
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: lightskyblue;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
 } 
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: lightskyblue;
}

-->
</style>
<title>JMC illustration * juniebug.net</title></head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="darkgreen" alink="orchid"   
vlink="mediumspringgreen">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, MS Reference Sans Serif, Calibri">




<br>
<br>
<center>

<br><br><br>


    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <center><img src="artinvisibar.gif"></center>


<br>
    <center>
    <img src="logo-jmc1.gif">
    </center>
    <br>


<center>
<img src="artstrip1.jpg">

    <br>
<div id="gallery">
    <a href="port/momo-Rio2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" rel="lightbox[closeup]"><img src="port/thumbs/momorio-t.gif" width="51" height="55"></a>

<a href="port/ioiosam2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" rel="lightbox[closeup]"><img src="port/thumbs/ioiosam-t.gif" width="51" height="55"></a>

</div>








</center>



    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Leo, where did you see this link? I don't see it in my source code... I don't even know what it could be for...!!

Comment: sorry, my bad that was actually some malware on my browser.

Comment: The problem is that the css in the lightbox.css file isn't working. Try making the link with http instead of https.

Comment: @Leo, I tried changing the link to just http ... no change... darn it...

Comment: I just looked at your code and it is still `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />` using a https instead of http.  Is that because you tried it and then put it back?

Comment: @Leo: Yes! No effect, so I just switched it back. Is there anything else I can try...?

Comment: Yes, you could download the css and link to it on your own server. It is definitely a problem with accessing the css, so that is what you need to sort out.

Comment: @Leo, just tried this... linked to it locally... again, didn't solve the issue. Updated the live site, too, so you can have a look as well.

Comment: Can you try adding type="text/css" to your stylesheet link? So it looks like this `<link href="material/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />`

Comment: @LeoFarmer , changed that sheet link according to your suggestion-- no change. :( Again, updated the live site with this edit, too.
This is so confusing...

Comment: Can you try adding `charset="UTF-8"` to the css link? So it reads `<link href="material/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  charset="UTF-8"  />`

Comment: @Leo, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!! IT WORKS!!!! THANK YOU!! <3
Only thing is I do not see the navigation buttons, still!! How do I fix this tiny glitch?? (I updated the live site so you can see and test, too!)

Comment: @Leo : Nevermind!! Buttons are showing: I had to tweak the CSS a bit. Removed all instances of `url(../images/loading.gif` (and other button names) and replaced with `url(images/loading.gif'. The two dots were confusing the CSS as to where the files are!
But thank you SO MUCH for your help!!!

Comment: @Leo: Ahh... there's no place on this to mark my question as 'answered' and your post(s) as the answer... but-- again, thank you!!